# Read 8GB of json files and save on file necessary info

Tags: json, python-3.x, pandas

I have to analyse 8GB of Twitter data over several zipped files, it's 1 month of data with one hour frequency.
Each file contains several tweets in json format, each line is a tweet.

This is the code I am using now for the first screening:

```
import pandas as pd
import pathlib
import timeit
import zipfile


def main():

    twitter_files = list(pathlib.Path("TwitterData").iterdir())
    twitter_data = []

    for tfilename in twitter_files:
        with zipfile.ZipFile(tfilename, "r") as zfile:
            # each zip file should contain just one json file,
            # this loop it's added for security reason
            for filename in zfile.namelist():
                print(filename)
                with zfile.open(filename) as jfile:
                    df = pd.read_json(jfile, lines=True)
                    # Remove NaN and duplicated values
                    sub_df = df[[
                        "id_str",
                        "created_at",
                        "in_reply_to_status_id_str",
                        "text",
                        "entities",
                        "extended_entities",
                        "quoted_status_id_str",
                        "retweeted",
                        "truncated"
                    ]].dropna(
                        subset=["id_str", "created_at", "text"],
                        how="any"
                    ).drop_duplicates(subset="text")

                    twitter_data.append(sub_df)
                    del df, sub_df

    tweets_df = pd.concat(twitter_data)
    del twitter_data
    with open("./tweet_data.feather", "w") as ffile:
        tweets_df.to_feather(ffile.name)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    duration = timeit.timeit(main, number=1)
    print(f"time: {duration}")
```

I want to extract the info I need, save on file and then use this file for the final analysis (find the unique tweets, the number of retweets etc).

The problem, of course, is that my laptop memory runs out quite fast and the program reaches a date and stops before the end of the month.

I would like to find a more memory and, possible, time efficient way to save the data I need.

I was thinking to read line by line of the json files and save the "good" tweets, but I think this is an I/O bottleneck...

Do you have any better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see 2 options to improve this

- **Use less memory [primary]:** The reason you run out of memory is that you hold the full `tweets_df` in memory all the time (provided you can read all individual files, which seems to be the case). You delete `df` and `sub_df` and `twitter_data` after every file is read/processed, but your master dataframe `tweets_df` keeps growing without bounds. That's not good. I assume you do that because you directly write `.to_feather`, where you want/have to write the full file content at once. The solution is to focus only on the "cleaning" effort (reading a single file, clean it, and save that incremental data somewhere) without having to hold all data in memory. To do that, write data in small batches by chosing a target format to which you can **append** data, without having to hold the full dataframe in memory all the time (simplest: append to a csv file, properly: append to a database table, disk-space conscious compromise: append to HDF). The burden of "holding all data" should be on the disk/database, not on your memory variable.
- **Speed/performance [secondary]:** You remove duplictes after reading every file. You could do that after every 2nd, 5th, 10th,.. file. You would reduce computational effort, and maybe further reduce memory (are you sure you don't have any duplicates across files?)

Edit: A third improvement would be to **run the code in parallel** (possible if step 1 is implemented, and the single master dataframe `tweets_df` is removed and processing happens in small batches). You can then run the script on n separate instances, each instance processing only a small number of source files, in parallel. That can be implemented to either produce n separate output files (structurally equal) which would need to be concated once in the end (a very quick operation), or appending on the fly into a single output file/database (with a wait condition/write lock). Either case, it's a speedup of approximately 1/n (a little less, given a bit of waiting will be required for the writing, or the concating in the end).

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer! I like the idea to use a database table. I never used database and I am looking into it. With pandas I could use `to_sql`, so I create the database and then save it into a file, is this what you meant?

Comment: Why don't you try `.to_csv` first with the flag `mode=a` for append? That's really a 30 second change.. That removes `tweets_df` entirely. I would focus on fixing the code logic first, and only once your batch processing works start optimizing the output data type and experiment with csv vs hdf vs sql

Comment: See my edited answer for a reason why I would fix the logic first and only then take care of the exact output format. If you chose to parallelize (the new idea that I added), your consideration of "save to database" vs. "save to csv file" vs. "save in an entirerly different place and format" will lead to different answers. Your question here is about "code" performance - let's achieve that with the simplest means (IMO a csv file)

Comment: Thanks @KingOtto. I agree to work before on the logic. I tried to append on a CSV file, it takes around 40min, the file is around 9GB and the laptop memory used it's pretty constant.
I am also thinking about the next step, i.e. how to analyse this CSV file, as I have to do some statistical analysis on it.

Comment: Great! Open a new question for that, once you figure out where the problem is! :) Don't forget to break down your problem. Question 1 was: How to process "infinite amounts" of data without running out of memory (-> use "appending", done). Next question might be "How to save this is a disk-space efficient way", or "How to run large-scale transformation on the full dataset?" It is surely less than 9GB when loaded into pandas, so maybe it is "good enough" anlready, and some of these questions can be ignored for now... Have fun experimenting with it :)